# Using Input types for query arguments

Tags: node.js, graphql

Is it a bad practice to use graphql input types for query arguments like its commonly done in mutations, for example

`createPost(CreatePostInput!): CreatePostPayload`

I see that a lot of api's use separate queries to fetch an entity by different fields, for example

```
userByEmail(email: String!): User
userByName(name: String!): User
```

as opposed to

`user(email: String, name: String): User`

This makes sense, but some queries end up requiring more than one argument, for example paginated results. One might need for example, to modify the start/end cursor, results per page, ordering and others, plus the main query might need more than one argument to find the entities, so these queries end up with 5-6 different arguments.

The question is, why don't people use input types for these?

To the answer below, I can't help but wonder why people deem this

```
query ($category: String, $perPage: Number, $page: Number, $sortBy: String) {
    posts(category: $category, perPage: $perPage, page: $page, sortBy: $sortBy) {
        ...
    }
}
```

friendlier than this

```
query( $input: PostQueryInput ) {
    posts(input: $input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it because the input types can only contain primitives? I find this really confusing why its better in one case and worse in another.

I know that people are not forced to to this, you can do it as you like, but in the majority of graphql api's I think it is not done like this and I wonder why might that be - people must have a reason not to do this.

Comment: just different needs/usage simplicity [both client/server] ... mutation works on entities, [typed] sets

Comment: I updated my initial question with a bit more information, because your answer didn't really answer my question, so I thought the question itself might not be clear enough.